# Tomcat/OpenSSL (and Chrome on Android): how to disable request for client certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, ssl, openssl

**Background:**

I'm working on a Grails application deployed on Tomcat. The entire site uses HTTPS (delegated to OpenSSL with the APR native libraries). When I visit the site from an Android phone using Chrome, I get the following prompt for a client certificate (which is a major usability problem). By looking at a tcpdump, it appears that OpenSSL is indeed asking for a certificate.

We do not need nor want client certificate authentication (note that the site does require a regular user/password authentication for the non-public content). For reasons unknown, this prompt appears on Chrome on Android but not with other browsers (all desktop browsers, Safari on iPad and others).

I read about the [SSL_VERIFY_NONE](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) option supported by OpenSSL (which appears to be the applicable one here) but how to configure it when OpenSSL is called behind the scenes by Tomcat? Neither that option (valid programmatically) nor the `-verify <depth>` [option](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html) (valid for the OpenSSL client) can be used in this case.

**TL;DR:** How to configure Tomcat and/or OpenSSL to avoid asking the client browser for a *client* certificate? Whatever we do, we must on the server side, this is a public internet site.

Thank you.

[image: certificate prompt]

[image: SSL dump]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say which version of Tomcat you are using so I am going to assume 7.0.x You need to add the following to your HTTPS connector in server.xml

```
SSLVerifyClient="none"
```

Details of this, all all the other SSL configuration options are in the docs:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_APR/Native

Answer (score -1):

Off topic, but it's the [`clientAuth`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) attribute in the Connector element.

Comment: Not in this case it isn't. The OP is using the APR/native connector not the BIO or NIO connector where clientAuth would be the correct attribute to use.

Comment: @MarkThomas That raises the age-old question of why two connectors for the same purpose have differently named attributes.

Comment: BIO and NIO use JSSE which exposes one set of configuration options and APR/native uses OpenSSL which has a different set. There are enough subtle differences (even between the configuration options that look the same on the surface) that keeping them separate was judges to be less confusing than trying to combining them.